# Filter for distinct counts

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to count the number of times each category of feathers appear in the dataset, and then filter only for those that have been counted more than 5 times when the column `beak` has the category `long`.

However, I'm getting the following error:

> near "(": syntax error

```
SELECT 
    land_birds.feather, land_birds.weight, COUNT(DISTINCT land_birds.feather) AS numFeathers,
    land_birds.size, sea_birds.beak
     
FROM
    land_birds
INNER JOIN
    sea_birds
ON 
    land_birds.colour = sea_birds.colour
WHERE sea_birds.colour IN (SELECT colour from land_birds) AND beak LIKE 'Long'
GROUP BY feather
ORDER BY feather ASC
FILTER(WHERE numFeathers > 5)
```

Comment: `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT land_birds.feather) > 5`

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh I'm currently using sqlite online as I'm practicing the query implementation. How can I integrate your suggestion? I get a syntax error when I include `HAVING` as you did. It works correctly when I remove `HAVING`

Comment: I don't get it. You combine all land birds with all sea birds of the same color? So with 200 grey land birds and 150 grey sea birds, you create 30000 combinations? And of these you only keep combinations where the sea (?) bird's beak is long? Then you take these combinations and group them by the land (?) bird's feather type? And per feather tye you count how many distinct feather types the feather type has (one obviously!). And then you want to show the land birds weight and size for a feather type? Which birds exactly? Aren't there different birds with the same feather type?

Comment: All this looks so very wrong that I cannot even fathom what exactly you are trying to do. Please take some time to elaborate. How does the difference land/sea bird even come into play? You havent mentioned them in your explanation. Please explain thoroughly and show sample data and expected result.

Comment: Please also show your table descriptions. I wonder whether you actually want to join the two tables. Maybe what you really want is the union of the two sets (achieved with `UNION ALL` in SQL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter on information that is generated by grouping you use a `HAVING` clause which is placed immediately after the `GROUP BY` clause, like this:

```
SELECT
      land_birds.feather
    , land_birds.weight
    , COUNT(DISTINCT land_birds.feather) AS numFeathers
    , land_birds.size
    , sea_birds.beak
FROM land_birds
INNER JOIN sea_birds ON land_birds.colour = sea_birds.colour
WHERE beak LIKE 'Long'
GROUP BY land_birds.feather
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT land_birds.feather) > 5
ORDER BY land_birds.feather ASC
```

Whilst it may seem logical in the having clause to use the "numFeathers" alias you gave that calculation, **don't**. Reference the calculation itself instead. It may help to remember this that you can reference a grouping calculation in the having clause that does not appear in the select clause e.g. this would still work

```
SELECT
      land_birds.feather
    , land_birds.weight

    , land_birds.size
    , sea_birds.beak
FROM land_birds
INNER JOIN sea_birds ON land_birds.colour = sea_birds.colour
WHERE beak LIKE 'Long'
GROUP BY land_birds.feather
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT land_birds.feather) > 5
ORDER BY land_birds.feather ASC
```

Here that there is no column alias at all for that calculation.

---

Other observations about your query.

1. always use the table name (or table alias) when referring to columns throughout your query
2. the inner join condition about colour means there can only be rows in the result that exactly match that condition. Hence it is NOT required that you also include the same condition in the where clause.

One final note, please don't treat the having clause as a substitute for a where clause. The where clause occurs before the grouping and hence it reduces the amount of data to be grouped. A having clause filters on the generated information which can only exist after grouping. In short they are very different clauses with specific capabilities and uses.